# Detecting defective Led's in a Led array

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

Im busy working on a project to detect a faulty Led in an array, i have it working using a pi and a camera, but the problem i am having is i need a way so when a new array with more Led's is presented to the camera as a known good array it can be easily taught through a web server or something similar, so that it is easier for the end user to teach new arrays knowing the amount of led's that should be seen on a perfect array.

Comment: you would be better finding a tutorial to do this raver than coming here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but iv'e looked everywhere for a tutorial with no avail, that's why i posted on here